# Is any 'Topic' equivalent in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have two Python processes where each one consume messages from multiprocessing.Queue.
Messages are pushed to those queue in the main thread. 
The problem is that messages sent to those two queues are the same (intentionally), so my question is:
is there any 'Topic' equivalent in Python ? (One message can be consumed by two processes, before removing). It's not must have, but I am just confused about making it in a better way ;)

Comment: What do you mean by Topic? Do you want to mark each item with a Topic, so that consumers can select items only by Topic? Why do you use a single queue, instead of one queue per topic?

Comment: By 'Topic' I mean: I want to have single 'queue', but messages are not removed from queue until predefined  number of reads. I just want to eliminate two queues containing the same messages (two processes doing different things with them)

Comment: Do the processes know whether they are the first or second to handle an item? Are the tasks sequential, i.e. each item goes through A then B, or are they independent, i.e. each item may go A->B, B->A or both A and B at the same time?

Comment: They are totally independent..

Comment: The `Queue` data type is just a simple FIFO queue; it's not a messaging system. If you want features like topics, persistence, etc, use an actually messaging server like rabbitmq or something similar.

Comment: I am aware of such kind of solutions, and I don't want to use it in that case. Anyway Thanks for suggestion ;)